# Recruiters are asking me for a JavaScript portfolio. What do I do?

Tags: portfolio

I am transitioning from being a Java developer to being a JavaScript one. Some prospective employers have asked to see a portfolio. My primary focus is UI coding, not pretty design. In that case, why would I need a portfolio? Am I just classed as a "front end guy", and hence need a portfolio?

If the answer is yes, what would said portfolio consist of? Some kind of arbitrary JavaScript project that shows off my skills?

Comment: Do you use frameworks like node, angular, react or anything?

Comment: Who's asking?  Hiring manager?  HR?  This might be a clue as to the sophistication level of who's asking.  A guy knows "pretty design" when he sees it but wouldn't know good, maintainable, robust code might ask to see something like that. Edit:  This [link](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18853/is-it-considered-a-good-idea-to-bring-along-a-programming-portfolio-to-an-interv?rq=1) has some good ideas, too.

Comment: It's coming through recruiters as one of the first things a client asks for after they scan my resume. Since I say that I don't have one, I am rejected. Coming from the Java world, code samples are rarely asked for. I guess it must be a convention in the GUI world..

Answer (score 4):

That's a rather unusual career shift from a strongly typed programming language to something that is client side web code to drive UI presentation such as ajax, or events. Are you planning to try nodejs or something within that field or just "javascript" in general?

In any event, as with Java, it's always nice to have sample code to give to employers. With JavaScript the quality of code is vastly different and someone with little programming knowledge can write "code" to drive simple things on the webpage such as expanding divs or the likes. If you are into nodejs, I would imagine a company has learnt the vast differences in talent for JavaScript developer and would want to see what sort of talent you have with JavaScript before bringing you in for a interview. They wouldn't want to waste time with someone who has very little programming knowledge.

Comment: Good question. I love rich GUI programming. That's why I'm transitioning to it. I want to make programming fun again for me; having done Java for 16 years now, it's gotten old and stale. Specific JS frameworks are Angular, Node and Backbone.

Comment: @AndrewB Do keep in mind that the enjoyment comes with a fairly heavy pay cut. Be sure to consider if that's a dealbreaker for you or not!

Comment: @AndrewB I would say yes definitely build a portfolio with Angular, Node, and Backbone if you know them. Just make simple programs to demonstrate you understand those specific frameworks and push them up to github or something. I know some startups are looking for that and they pay handsomely for someone with that kind of JavaScript knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

## Why do the minimum?

Applying for work is a competition of skills, background and work ethic. Doing whatever you can to stand above other candidates is how you win the offer.

Is they're asking for a portfolio then chances are that a great deal of people applying for these roles are doing this, if they weren't then this employer asking for it means that they likely are now.

## What does the recruiter expect from me?

In this case the person requesting your portfolio is a recruiter so it's likely they've been asked to do so by the company in question. Since you don't know whether they're expecting a summary of projects or a code based portfolio then I would produce both as you can always re-use these in future interviews.

## How do you actually do this with JavaScript?

I've interviewed a number of JavaScript programmers who have provided a portfolio of work. Typically they will send me a Github account to look at their work however it's also not unusual for front end designers to bring me a printed portfolio of their work to an interview. I remember this, and react to it quite positively.

## How to produce a printed portfolio as a backend developer?

Understandably you are more of a backend than front end guy so it's difficult for you to produce a very visual portfolio for interviews. To overcome this I would write a summary of the projects that you've worked on and some of the design decisions you've made.

Basically a timeline of projects that you have worked on along the general lines of:

> **Project:** Article Summaries for example website
>
> **Language(s) and framework(s) used:** AngularJS
>
> **Description:** Created a responsive article listing for example website. I designed this using the awesomo design pattern to allow
> future developers to quickly understand the code base and allow it to be changed quickly and easily as the need arises. This project also exposed me to exampleX and exampleY which I now have a strong working knowledge of.

Comment: yep, even printed samples are good

Comment: @Kilisi I agree. I think it's also worth mentioning that it's important to have both in case your first round interview is with a non-technical person (such as a HR rep). This is where a project summary will show its strength.

Answer (score 2):

If a prospective employer is asking for a portfolio, then yes, obviously it would help if you had one. All else being equal, between two candidates one with a portfolio and one without, most employers would take the one with the portfolio. So if you want to be competitive then you make one.

The sorts of things you would have ideally (if I was asking for it) was some projects that you had either done or contributed to that I could have a quick look at to judge your competence. Anything from a little game with some .js bells and whistles, to a piece of financial software where the calculations are done via .js, or even just some standalone scripts to make a ball bounce across the screen. The bigger the project the better though, something fairly comprehensive that shows you have thorough knowledge of your subject.

Most people who have something would point to something open source they have done, which to my mind is one of the primary reasons for contributing to open source in the first place because it's an easy way to showcase your skills.

I particularly like open source because I can then see not only how good your code is but see HOW you write it (commenting, formatting etc,.)

Answer (score -1):

> Also, if the answer is yes, what would said portfolio consist of?

GitHub allows you to host web pages via [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com). JavaScript works on GitHub Pages, so this is a good way to start a JavaScript portfolio.